# How to fix Python libraries not importing after macOS Catalina install?

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

I have updated to macOS Catalina, and since then I am unable to run any of the Python scripts/Jupyter notebooks because of the `ModuleNotFoundError`. I definitely had the modules installed, but it seems like Python can't find them for some reason? Even the most basic libraries like `numpy` can't be imported without reinstalling them.

I could reinstall all of the modules when I need to but:

a) it's a pain

b) they are already somewhere

c) I have already ran into problems trying to reinstall some of the less common libraries.

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Comment: I think they stopped including python2 by default in mac OS catalina, maybe double check which python version you are using?

Comment: If you use anaconda for python distribution, you can check the for the installed package and maybe reinstall anaconda

Comment: I don't know the answer for fixing this issue, but if you use a requirements.txt file for your setup, you'll be able to reinstall really easily. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files